# multiple function within routes in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I'm newbie to express js i want to put multiple functions within routes, kindly explain me how to add multiple function within route, i have 2 functions in company.js but i don't know how to export it and add it in index.js

index.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var path = require('path');

// Rest API
require(path.join(__dirname, './', 'company'))(router);


// Homepage/Client 
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client', 'index.html'));
});

module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    // set authentication routes
    require('./authentication.js')(app, passport);

    // set other routes
    app.use('/', router);
};
```

company.js

```
  var sockets = require('../utilities/socket'); 
  var authenticationMiddleware = 
  require('../middlewares/authentication.js');
  var companyModel = require('../models/company.js');

var getCompanyProfile = function(router){

  router.post('/api/v1/profile/fetchCompany', authenticationMiddleware.isLoggedIn, 
        function(req, res) {
            companyModel.getCompanyProfile(req['user'].id_user,
                                            function(result){
                                                return res.json(result);
                                            });
          }
    );

},
var saveCompanyProfile = function(router){

  router.post('/api/v1/profile/saveCompany', authenticationMiddleware.isLoggedIn, 
      function(req, res) {
        companyModel.saveCompanyProfile(req,
                        function(result){
                          return res.json(result);
                        });
      }
  );

}

module.exports = getCompanyProfile;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export those two functions as follows

```
module.exports = {
   getCompanyProfile: getCompanyProfile,
   saveCompanyProfile: saveCompanyProfile 
}
```

and import in **index.js** as follows

```
const company = require('./company.js');
company.getCompanyProfile(router);
company.saveCompanyProfile(router);
```

Comment: raises error like                   
      router.post('/api/v1/profile/getCompanyProfile',authenticationMiddleware.isLoggedIn,
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Comment: You need to pass the router param to those functions like `company.getCompanyProfile(router);`

Comment: I just gave a general approach of exporting and importing exported functions @veeran I just forgot to edit it as per your question.. Hope you got an idea cheers